# Refit XmlContentSerializer isn't found when making .net 6 console app

Tags: refit

I have a .net 6 console application. I have included Refit v 6.3.2, but when I have:

```
using Refit;

var settings = new RefitSettings
{
   ContentSerializer = new XmlContentSerializer()
}
```

It says XmlContentSerializer can't be found. The suggestions are only to generate the class. What am I missing here? The NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer() was found just fine, but I need the xml one. Any ideas as to what this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the add Refit.Xml nuget package